# How do I minimize disk space usage

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, efficiency

One of my machines is the **2GB EeePC Surf**, a neat netbook with very limited resources. So limited that right now, I have **22MB** free space left.

On it, I'm running **Arch Linux** with the **Openbox** DE and a host of needed applications for it to function as a mobile PC.

What methods are available to stamp out some unnecessary used space?

Comment: @Stefan how much RAM does it have? (just wondering if it's feasible to put things like /tmp in ram)

Comment: @Stefan also... if you're willing to go the experimental route... btrfs supposedly supports a compressed file system (or is going to?) maybe check that out

Comment: @stefan also `du -sh /` to see where most of your space is being used.

Comment: @xeno, 490MB RAM, and it's `du -sh /*`?

Comment: @Stefan so it is... oops... of you can `cd /` and run `du -sh *` and drill down... (you don't really have enough ram to store stuff in it)

Comment: @Stefan I'm curious why arch (for this box)? it's not really the trimmest distro... esp given it installs all the header files.

Comment: @xeno, Sorry, I missed your comment there.. I used arch because  I'm arch fluent, but I tried debian on it first. Worked really well with the laptop, but not my thing...

Comment: @Stefan yeah I'm not a debian fan either. Just saying that arch isn't designed to be trim filesystem wise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are some points you could start with:

- Have a look at the packages installed
  on your system with `pacman -Q` and
  remove the ones you don't need. A
  good start may be to append the `-t`
  switch:

  > Restrict or filter output to packages
  >   not required by any currently
  >   installed package.
- Clean the package cache of pacman
  with `pacman -Sc`
- Always use `pacman -Rs` to remove
  also unused package dependencies.
- To find "big files" and folders which
  use large parts of the disk, a nice
  addition to `du` is `xdiskusage`.
  This little tool lets you quickly
  browse your filesystem and see
  graphical representation of the disk
  usage of the folders.

Comment: `pacman -cc` to clean the entire cache including installed packages I think. Not normally recommended as you may want those as backups later.

Comment: @xeno, I already mount a diretory on my desktop for `--cachedir`, so I don't need to keep any pkg files.

Comment: For clearing space on `/`, I found [`pacgraph`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/pacgraph/) really useful. It can sort your installed packages by size, so you can better prioritise what it makes sense to remove. (It can even draw SVG dependency graphs, but is useful from just the command line.)

Comment: [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) is a cool command-line alternative to `xdiskusage`. [Baobab](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab) is by far the best graphical app for this purpose though.

Answer (score 14):

***WARNING: These ideas are only for users who are well-versed in both Linux as a whole and Arch Linux.***

If you're willing to tread into dangerous territory, you can slim a base Arch install down to less than 500MB installed. This requires doing some very dangerous things:

1. removing all unnecessary locales (already covered)
2. removing any firmware files not needed to run your system (from `/usr/lib/firmware`)
3. removing any kernel modules not needed to run your system (from `/usr/lib/modules/...`)
4. removing any `.a` files in `/usr/lib` (only if you never use the system to compile software. note: this includes using `makepkg`)
5. removing everything in `/usr/include` (only if you never use the system to compile software)
6. removing unneeded documentation from `/usr/share/doc` and `/usr/share/info`
7. (VERY BAD IDEA unless maybe for a server) removing man pages from `/usr/share/man`
8. (also a bad idea) removing unneeded terminal descriptors from `/usr/share/terminfo` and unneeded timezone files from `/usr/share/zoneinfo`
9. (DANGEROUS) running `strip *` on all folders containing executable binaries (`/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`)
10. (in extreme situations) using a tool such as `upx` to compress larger binaries (the Samba binaries lend themselves to this well as they tend to be quite large since they are often compiled statically.) Also note that using `upx` means the entire uncompressed binary must fit in RAM during execution, so be weary on systems with low RAM.

Before you do ANY of this, MAKE A FULL BACKUP of your system. Linux thankfully makes this relatively easy - if you can attach and mount an external volume (e.g. a USB drive) you can do something like `cd / && tar -cf /mnt/usb/mySystem.tar /` to backup the entire system.

Once again, note that I do not actually recommend doing the above (especially 7 through 9) unless you have ***in-depth knowledge, experience and understanding of Linux internals and Arch Linux***. Playing with just about any of the files I've listed can damage a system in horrible ways, so you've been warned. If you don't know if your system needs a certain firmware file, module, etc. then do your research before you mess with it. (Be warned that removing kernel modules that your system needs can result in an unbootable system, or a system with no keyboard/network card/sound/display/etc. support, or all sorts of other unexplainable behavior.)

Also please note that any package upgrades can and will restore many of the files you remove above. If you do decide to go this route, you may wish to eventually script the removal of unneeded files and run your script after every major package upgrade. (Example: upgrading the kernel will bring back all the kernel modules as well as upgrade via dependency the linux-firmware package bringing back all of the firmware in `/usr/lib/firmware`.)

Finally, keep an eye on `/var/log` as the journal files will grow over time. You can remove past journals but keep the current ones by doing something like `rm *\@*.journal` in your journal folder.

I've successfully ran a NAS server off a 512MB Disk-on-Module device for months using these techniques, however they're still not for the faint of heart. (I've also used LinuxFromScratch to build a similar project in only 128MB of storage, but that's another story...)

---

EDIT/ADD:

Here's a few more methods you can use to try to get some extra space:

- Getting rid of `libgo`. The `libgo` library comes with `gcc-libs` and is AFAIK only used by applications written in the Go language. I can't think of any application I use that needs that library. On my system it's 40MB in size. When you're trying to slim way down, that's a lot of space. I've removed it from my "mini" installs with no ill effects on anything I do (but again, that's me, YMMV!)
- Shrinking `libicudata.so`. It's 27MB on my system. It's basically a ton of unicode/locale data compressed into a library object. There is a tool online that can make smaller versions of this file, but it hasn't been updated for the current version (and you can't use older files in newer releases.) I haven't tried doing this by hand, but if you can figure out how, you can shave about 20-22MB off this file.
- If you use Python, you can save 37MB or so by removing the `test` library from python2: `rm -r /usr/lib/python2.7/test` and about 66MB by removing it for python3: `rm -r /usr/lib/python3.6/test`.
- Again for Python, you can get rid of the `.pyo` files and the `.py` files. The `.pyo` files are "optimized" files, but Python never really uses them. The `.py` files are the raw source code for the standard library. The only files Python normally reads when running Python code is the `.pyc` (python compiled) files. `cd /usr/lib/python2.7 && find . -name "*.pyo" -exec rm -v {} \;` and `cd /usr/lib/python3.6 && find . -name "*.pyo" -exec rm -v {} \;`
- Removing unnecessary locale data. There's an AUR package called `localepurge` which automates this. Otherwise, you have to play around in `/usr/share/locale`. You need to keep your own locale and `locale.alias`. For me here in the US, keeping `en_US` and `locale.alias` and removing everything else shaved off about 80MB.

Now, what I want to see is a tool that analyzes your system and determines which kernel modules you need, and also which firmware files you need. That would be a nice way to "safely" clean out those folders...

Or, maybe someone should put together an Arch "distro" that uses `uClibc` or `diet-libc` or something similar. That might be a fun summer project. :-)

Comment: I'm interested in doing this too.. the firmware seems the biggest gain for me, I'm trying to make a small vagrant box so only need the firmware required to run arch on virtualbox... is there an easy way to find out what firmware is required?

Comment: warning: just tried `upx`, it doesnt play well with all types of exectuables, ex: it left mysqld & mongodb segfaulting

Comment: **re: Package upgrades can and will restore many of the files you remove**. By extending /etc/pacman.conf with `NoExtract` definitions (can be defined multiple times) you can solve that issue permanently. One example to only update update Realtek nic drivers: `NoExtract = usr/lib/firmware/* !usr/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/*`

Comment: `find /usr/lib/firmware -atime +30` would find firmware files that is not accessed in 30 days. It should be safe to delete those files.

Answer (score 9):

## TLDR

```
journalctl --vacuum-size=100M #remove all logs, only retain 100mb
pacman -Scc #remove all package installation files (obsolete and current)
pacman -S bleachbit
bleachbit -c system.*
```

## First, what's big on the system

```
du -d1 -h / 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

This shows a sorted list of the largest dirs in `/`
You can do two levels down:

```
du -d2 -h / 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

My result is:

```
0       /proc
0       /sys
0       /tmp
12K     /dev
12K     /srv
16K     /lost+found
632K    /run
4.3M    /boot
13M     /opt
15M     /etc
75M     /root
93M     /home
2.4G    /var
3.2G    /usr
221G    /mnt
227G    /
```

I ignore `/mnt` (because that's an external drive)
Two dirs stand to mind: `var` and `usr`.
Let's see what's inside:

```
du -d1 -h /var /usr 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

Then, a little bit deeper:

```
du -d1 -h /var/log /usr/share /usr/lib /var/cache 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

## Let's start with the logs

I have 717mb in `/var/log`.

I'm not a fan of deleting directories randomly, so let's do it the clean way:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 728.7M on disk.
```

Let's leave only 100mb of logs:

```
journalctl --vacuum-size=100M
...
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/ba5391...b.journal (8.0M).
...
Vacuuming done, freed 616.6M of archived journals on disk.
```

More info here on how to configure journalctl [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl).

## Packages

I have `660M    /var/cache/pacman`. It was 1.8gb, but I ran `pacman -Sc` to remove unused packages.  Let's remove the rest:

```
pacman -Scc
```

## /usr/share/locale

A lot of users do remove it, or at least clean it up. But I might be a [problem](https://blog.hartwork.org/?p=1516). But checkout bleachbit (next paragraph).

## Bleachbit

[Automatic cleaner](http://www.bleachbit.org/documentation/command-line). Will delete a lot of stuff, but for it was mostly locales.

```
$ pacman -S bleachbit
$ bleachbit -p system.*
Disk space to be recovered: 488.8MB
$ bleachbit -c system.*
```

You can look for more stuff to delete:

```
bleachbit --list
bleachbit -p thunderbird.*
```

Comment: On quite a minimal Arch Linux 64-bit installation, the total installed size of the bleachbit package is 209.70 MiB: `Total Installed Size:  209.70 MiB`

Comment: Tip: if you do `du -xkd1` in the `/` directory, it will not descend into other mountpoints.

Answer (score 3):

On the 4GB disk in my Eeepc with Ubuntu it helped to remove some locale files (from /usr/share/locale) and Gnome help files (from /usr/share/gnome/help/). Both were installed for languages which I don't use. Not sure if Arch Linux even installs all those files, though.

Comment: yes... `du -hs /usr/share/locale` is about 300MB... can I just `rm -rf` the unneeded files?

Comment: @Stefan http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale If you edit `/etc/locale.gen` and re-run `locale-gen`, you should have fewer pre-compiled locales.  If you want to free up more space in an automated way, you might want to try http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=11975 too.  (But it's unsupported and if it breaks your system, you get to keep the pieces.)

Comment: [localepurge](https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=localepurge) is a script to remove disk space wasted for unneeded localizations. Edit */etc/locale.nopurge* first :) It cleaned up ~300 MB first time I've runned it and dozens MB each couple of months. Is available in AUR.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest AUTOMATING looking at your own very old files and see if its necessary and remove them. This can done with two things. One writing a `find` command to look for very old files. and using this output (maybe pipe) to `lograte` script to archive files older than says 3 months and delete files older than 3 months in archive and send a mail to 1 day before deleting it. So that you can be sure you have not lost any important file. So in finally you would need the following commands to accomplish the above:

```
find , | , logrotate , mail, crontab
```

I am not going to spoon feed you. I have done this before has been quite successful with this and was later scrapped because we decided to go with `nagios` for monitoring as it was more tuned to do that kind of stuff in a corp server. I think if `mail` command is not already configured for you, you might find that the toughest rest should be straight forward. This all needs to done through bash scripting and putting that in cron job and to run every x days. Learn bash scripting, it will be very useful not only for this but to make your life easier with *nix. So use your favourite internet search engine and read about the above commands and bash scripting. And tie them together and test it. Once satisfied put to regular use. I assure it will be fun doing this. You will learn a lot if you haven't done this kinda before.

- Hope that helps

Comment: Fro my experience i found that most disk occupying things are not OS related files but my own files accumulated over a period of time , hence i suggested the above.