# Fedora 21 akmods.service long boot time

Tags: fedora, systemd

I updated from 20 to 21 today and while booting into 21 I noticed the boot time being really long. The result of `systemd-analyze blame`: http://pastie.org/9794252

`systemctl status akmods.service`:

```
● akmods.service - Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/akmods.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2014-12-22 15:00:42 CET; 5min ago
 Main PID: 849 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/akmods.service

Dec 22 15:00:42 fundora akmods[849]: Checking kmods exist for 3.17.7-200.fc20.x86_64[  OK  ]
Dec 22 15:00:42 fundora systemd[1]: Started Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages.
```

Why is akmod.service taking so long?

Answer (score 3):

Akmods are a thing that basically ensures you have certain (often third party) modules/drivers available for the current kernel:

> RPM Fusion/Livna distributes kernel-modules as kmod packages that
>   contain modules precompiled for the latest kernels released by Fedora.
>   That works fine for most people, but it doesn't work on systems with
>   use different kernel -- like a self-compiled kernel, an older Fedora
>   kernel or the quickly changing kernels from updates-testing/rawhide.
>   The kmods-srpms can easily be rebuilt for those kernels using rpmbuild
>   with a kmod-specific parameter that defines what kernel to build the
>   kmod for. But that requires some knowledge of how to build rpms; this
>   is what the script akmods tries to make easier for the end user, as it
>   does all the steps required to build a kmod.rpm for the running kernel
>   from a kmod-srpm.
>
> But the user still needs to do something manually when he needs a kmod
>   for a newly installed kernel. This is what the akmodsd daemon is
>   trying to fix: it's a script normally started from init on bootup that
>   checks if all kmods are present. If a kmod is not found then akmods
>   tries to rebuild kmod.srpms found in a certain place in the
>   filesystem; if that works it will install the rebuilt kmod into the
>   running kernel automatically.
>
> This is similar to dkms, but has one important benefit: one only needs
>   to maintain a single kmod spec file which can be used both in the
>   repos buildsystem and on the clients systems if needed.

<sup>[Source: RPMfusion:Packaging/KernelModules/Akmods](http://rpmfusion.org/Packaging/KernelModules/Akmods)</sup>

So it takes a long time either because a new module may need to be built, or it is just checking whether the right modules are available which may also  take a while.

**Method 1:**
It is possible to disable it with:

```
sudo systemctl disable akmods
```

However when you update the kernel it will likely not have the right drivers available, unless you run akmods manually:

```
sudo akmods
```

Note that the appropriate `kernel-devel` package should be installed and up to date, and this probably won't work with +debug kernels.

I have done this and it seems to work so far *(boots in well under a minute with the [journal size reduced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139515/52956) as well (on an old system with a HDD))*. You can go further disabling various other services as well (see **N**ote **B**elow), but it all depends whether you want a leaner slightly faster system, or one that works with most stuff ( e.g. I did not use LVM on older systems). These services exist for generally useful reasons...

**Method 2:**

Or you remove it with `sudo dnf erase akmods`, but this will likely remove the modules that depend on it (often third party ones from RPMfusion or similar). You can see what packages need akmod with `sudo rpm -q --whatrequires akmods`:

```
~$ sudo rpm -q --whatrequires akmods
akmod-wl-6.30.223.248-9.fc22.x86_64
akmod-VirtualBox-4.3.32-1.fc22.x86_64
```

So in my case the akmods are for the VirtualBox and wireless drivers, which I sort of need.

---

N.B. another method of examining boot services etc is to run:

```
systemd-analyze plot > systemd-analyze.svg
```

This produces a image which you can use to determine what services are taking the longest time. Also covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/763070/178596).

Comment: Honestly running akmod should bee part of kernel upgrade or dkms drivers installation or some kind of specialized post transaction, turning it into a service was not a great idea in my opinion. Not sure how much it has to do with the fact that a yum-plugin-post-transaction-actions alternative is not available yet.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti my guess is that would need to built into the offical kernel upgrade packages, which they probably dont want to!

Comment: Not necessarily, as I said it could be some kind of specialized post transaction, where dnf trigger post transaction actions whenever there is a kernel upgrade. It would help with grub update also and would allow for disablement in case someone do not want this behavior.