# How to remove entries in coredumpctl with missing corefile

Tags: linux, core-dump

For some reason `coredumpctl` keeps hoarding entries that don't have a corefile available any more. How can I clean these up so they don't clog the output?

Comment: From the `systemd-coredump` man page, *Note that the removal of core files from the file system and the purging of journal entries are independent, and the core file may be present without the journal entry, and journal entries may point to since-removed core files.*

Comment: ... see also [Cleaning up coredumpctl list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220420/cleaning-up-coredumpctl-list)

Comment: The entries you see in `coredumpctl` actually come from `journalctl` (see: `journalctl -t systemd-coredump`). As mentioned in the answers to [How do I clear journalctl entries for a specific unit only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272662/273579), there isn't an easy way to clear entries from `journalctl` except for rewriting the journal file.

Answer (score 0):

List all the coredump entries with their ID:

`coredumpctl list`

or

`coredumpctl list --no-pager --no-legend`

Identify the ones without a core file.

These entries will have a size of 0 or a message indicating that the core file is missing.

`coredumpctl remove <ID>`

or

> Since `coredumpctl list` lists the dumpfiles recorded by the journal, you may manually delete the dump files from `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` that are not listed.
>
> Browse the dump files, compare the files with the results from the command and delete the files not listed.

- [Cleaning up coredumpctl list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481393/515538)

Remove each entry with:

`rm /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.<ID>.<executable>.core`

Run the list command again to check, that the entries have been removed.

- [How to safely delete core dump info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440041/how-to-safely-delete-core-dump-info)

> In order to cleanup all dumped core stored by `systemd-coredump`, you can run (as root):
>
> `systemd-tmpfiles --clean`
>
> To an answer your direct question, yes, the coredump files are safe to delete.

- [coredumpctl — Retrieve and process saved core dumps and metadata](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/coredumpctl.html)
- [systemd-coredump, systemd-coredump.socket, systemd-coredump@.service — Acquire, save and process core dumps](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html)

**Update:**

**There is no straightforward method to clear single entries from `journalctl` other than rewriting the journal file and this doesn't seem to be a straightforward task.**

> From @aviro | The OP doesn't want to remove the files from `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`. Exactly the opposite. He want to remove or filter out `coredumpctl` entries (or to be more exact: `journalctl` entries) where there is no file available in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`. His complaint is that `_coredumpctl` keeps hoarding entries that don't have a corefile available any more. _ Hoarding means he doesn't want to show entries where core files are not available anymore in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`.

- [journalctl — Print log entries from the systemd journal](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)

To filter entries where the core dump file is missing, you can use `journalctl` with the message filter, replace  with the actual ID of the list entry:

`journalctl -u systemd-coredump --grep="<ID>"`

> After some research I found that you can't delete logs for a specific systemd unit, because the logs are interlaced and if you delete only one unit you'll corrupt the logs, so `journalctl` doesn't let you

- [journalctl - remove logs of a specific unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718019/journalctl-remove-logs-of-a-specific-unit)

> Use my Python 3 `program copy_journal.py` on the journal files in `/var/log/journal` from which you want to remove entries.

- [How do I clear journalctl entries for a specific unit only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272662/how-do-i-clear-journalctl-entries-for-a-specific-unit-only/)

> systemd's journal is designed to prevent this kind of tampering.
>
> The journal file format is documented [here](https://systemd.io/JOURNAL_FILE_FORMAT/) and it describes its support for *in-line Forward Secure Sealing*:
>
> Tag objects are used to seal off the journal for alteration. In regular intervals a tag object is appended to the file. The tag object consists of a SHA-256 HMAC tag that is calculated from the objects stored in the file since the last tag was written, or from the beginning if no tag was written yet. The key for the HMAC is calculated via the externally maintained FSPRG logic for the epoch that is written into epoch. The sequence number seqnum is increased with each tag. [..]

- [Remove single line from journalctl file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454540/remove-single-line-from-journalctl-file)