# How do I clear journalctl entries for a specific unit only?

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I spent a few days writing a python script, and creating a systemd unit file for it. During testing, the script logged a lot of errors to journald. I would like to clear those errors from journald now that I'm done.

There are several ways to clear the entire journal, as described here: [How to clear journalctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl)
including using `journalctl --vacuum-time=2d`, using `journalctl --vacuum-size=500M`, and temporarily setting `SystemMaxUse=` in /etc/systemd/journald.conf to a very low value.

All of these appear to clear the entire journal, effecting all units. I just need to clear the entries for a single unit. Is this possible?

Comment: A possible approach is to write a program using [libsystemd's journal functions](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/journal/journal-file.h) to rewrite the journal file without the entries you want removed.

Answer (score 18):

Use my Python 3 program [copy_journal.py](https://github.com/Mortal/cournal/blob/master/copy_journal.py) on the journal files in `/var/log/journal` from which you want to remove entries.

For instance, to make a copy of `system.journal` without log entries for `NetworkManager.service`:

```
$ journalctl --file=system.journal | wc
    167    1934   18825
$ journalctl --file=system.journal | grep -v NetworkManager | wc
     77     881    8421
$ python3 copy_journal.py --remove-unit=NetworkManager.service system.journal system-without-nm.journal
$ journalctl --file=system-without-nm.journal | wc
     77     881    8421
```

Comment: Wow, huge work on this package!

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for a way to remove a specific message from the systemd journal. This didn't seem like an uncommon scenario (e.g. accidentally running a wrong command or having lots of spam).

It appears to be infeasible to redact specific entries by modifying an existing file, because the [systemd Journal format](https://systemd.io/JOURNAL_FILE_FORMAT/) is primarily designed to support appending, which involves optional compression, hashing, updating counters, indexing references to offsets and hashes. I tried this at first, but would not recommend anyone to do this.

To remove specific entries, I found that the next best thing is to generate a new log file based on the existing log file (e.g. the Python script from [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272662/how-do-i-clear-journalctl-entries-for-a-specific-unit-only/350640#350640) does this). **Systemd actually ships the necessary tools to easily modify log entries** using this principle.

### Short version

In essence, export the journal to a text format, and then convert it back to a journal:

- `journalctl --file=system.journal -o export | /lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=result.journal`

This mechanism can easily be extended by piping the initial output to a program/script (such as awk, sed, etc.) to do automatic filtering before piping it to `systemd-journal-remote`.

A more manual approach is to write the text to a file, modify the file by hand with a text editor and then converting it back to a `.journal` file. This is explained in more detail below.

### Long version

Here is the longer version, a step-by-step guide to modify an existing journal (tested on ArchLinux, using an Ubuntu live USB, systemd 246).

1. First, ensure that the journal has been closed. For example by shutting down your computer.
2. Boot a different device (via a bootable live USB for example). This is to be able to make changes without inadvertently impacting the journal.
3. To minimize accidental side effects, mount the original disk as read-only. For example:

   ```
   $ sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```

   another example, if you're using LUKS to encrypt the device:

   ```
   $ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 whateverName
   $ sudo mount -o ro /dev/mapper/whateverName /mnt
   ```
4. If your current device doesn't have systemd / journalctl, use a chroot to be able to use the binaries from your read-only disk. The minimum to get this to work is as follows:

   ```
   $ sudo mount --bind /tmp /mnt/tmp
   $ sudo mount --bind /tmp /mnt/var/tmp
   $ sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
   $ sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

   ---

---

5. When you are ready, export the journal.

   ```
   $ journalctl --file=system.journal -o export > /tmp/export.txt
   ```
6. Edit the export to redact, add, modify or remove entries. You can do this outside the chroot if you want to, e.g. with `vi -b /tmp/export.txt`.
   Example of the output: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/export/
7. When you have made the desired modifications, convert it back to a journal using `systemd-journal-remote`. This binary is not in bin / `$PATH`, so you need to use the absolute path to the program's location:

   ```
   $ /lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=/tmp/result.journal /tmp/export.txt
   ```
8. Verify that the journal has the desired output, e.g. by paging through the journal with:

   ```
   $ journalctl --file=/tmp/result.journal
   ```

   If you are satisfied, proceed with the next step. Otherwise repeat from step 6.

---

---

9. Exit the chroot (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or simply `exit`) and undo step 4, if needed:

   ```
   $ sudo umount /mnt/proc
   $ sudo umount /mnt/tmp
   $ sudo umount /mnt/var/tmp
   ```
10. **Now we are about to overwrite the original journal.**
    If you have mounted the volume as read-only (step 3), remount as writable.

    ```
    $ sudo mount -o remount,rw /mnt
    ```

    To avoid unwanted changes in file attributes or ownership, just replace the content instead of copying the file.

    ```
    # cat /tmp/result.journal > /mnt/var/log/journal/MACHINE_ID_HERE/system.journal
    ```

    or if you aren't running in a root shell, use `sudo tee outfile >/dev/null`, like this:

    ```
    $ </tmp/result.journal sudo tee /mnt/var/log/journal/MACHINE_ID_HERE/system.journal >/dev/null
    ```
11. Unmount the disk (from step 3 / step 10) if needed.

    ```
    $ sudo umount /mnt
    ```

    If you had opened an encrypted volume (at step 3), lock it again:

    ```
    $ sudo cryptsetup luksClose whateverName
    ```

Comment: I would say this is unnecessarily complicated – instead of having to use a liveCD in order to work on the "live" `system.journal` file, it'd be much easier to trigger a log rotation via journalctl and then do anything you like to the no-longer-active `system@[id].journal`.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Indeed, this (otherwise great) answer can be made much safer and simpler by replacing steps 1-4 with `journalctl --system --rotate`, replacing `system.journal` in steps 5 with the rotated name and replacing steps 9-11 with just a simple copy/move (like what's now in step 10, but to the rotated name)

Answer (score 1):

I copied here my answer from [duplicated question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78041598/4428260)

I couldn't find the specific version it became possible, journaltcl documentation doesn't even mention that --vacuum-time (or -size or -files) can be combined with --unit but I have ver:249, the vacuuming came in ver:218, and unit filter came in ver:195.

TLDR: Old and roundabout methods are no longer necessary:
To clean up all logs for a unit:
`journalctl --vacuum-time=1s --unit=your.service`

If you don't mind rotating logs of everything else AND you still find logs from your unit (meaning its last log haven't rotated yet) you can rotate in one go:
`journalctl --rotate --vacuum-time=1s --unit=your.service`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think think its possibble, because according to journalctl man page "Output is interleaved from all accessible journal files, whether they are rotated or currently being written".

You could however filter it by a unit - 'journalctl -u some.service' and then try to remove the log entries from the journal with your own script using cron.

Comment: It sounds like you are implying that there is a way to delete individual log entries from journald. Is there one? That would be very helpful.