# Whence does systemd determine the transient hostname?

Tags: boot, systemd

In RHEL 7.2, `systemd` starts up and determines the host's hostname. If `/etc/hostname` is unavailable (ie, removed), and `/etc/machine-info` is unavilable, and the kernel is not configured with that information (ie, `sysctl`'s `kernel.hostname`), `systemd` assigns a "transient" hostname to the host. The question is: from where does it determine this?

The host was originally named this way. I then cloned the host (it's a VM) and wiped all references to that name. But then during the boot process, very early, it gets set that way.

If I boot into `rescuemode` I can see that it sets the hostname very early:

```
[    0.456076] systemd[1]: systemd 208 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +AC
L +XZ)
[    0.456664] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization 'kvm'.
[    0.456955] systemd[1]: Running in initial RAM disk.
[    0.458496] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <badhostname.example.com>.
[    0.475394] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mapper-vgroot\x2dlvroot.device...
```

At the command prompt, it's set as a "transient" hostname:

```
# hostnamectl status
Transient hostname: badhostname.mydomain.com
...
```

It might be that it's not `systemd`: I even get this problem when using `init=/bin/bash`, but systemd is running within the initrd image.

- It's not set in grub or anything.
- It's not set by DHCP as networking is disabled at boot.
- It's not anywhere in the filesystem:

  ```
  # find / \( -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -path /run -prune \) -o -type f -exec grep -ilrF "${HOSTNAME}" {} +
  <some .git files>
  <history files of non-root user>
  ```

Somehow, the kernel or systemd is determining the old hostname and using it as a transient, and I'm at a complete loss as to how! . I did a `find ... -exec grep` with no results except `/var/log/dmesg`. I'm telling you, systemd has haunted my host!

EDIT 2: The only time I don't get it is if I boot into the provided rescue  initramfs. Apparently, the generated initramfs holds dirty secrets!

Comment: I've narrowed it down to 3 possibilities: (1) the initrd image, (2) even when not in networked mode, it uses DHCP to get the hostname -- possibly within initrd, (3) black magic.

Comment: As an aside, nice use of the word "whence."  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Don Crissti's insights and via process of elimination, it is concluded that the culprit is the initramfs image. Somehow `dracut` when it builds the image decides to include a cached version of the hostname (!?!).

Rebuilding the initrd/initram fs is covered [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1958) but in short (since you, dear reader might not have access), do

```
dracut -f -v
```