# journalctl: unrecognized option '--vacuum-size= '

Tags: systemd, logs, delete, systemd-journald, journalctl

All environment info on my os.

```
debian8@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
debian8@debian:~$ systemd --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
```

My journald.conf configuration.

sudo cat  /etc/systemd/journald.conf | grep -v "#"

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
Compress=yes
Seal=yes
SyncIntervalSec=5m
SystemMaxUse=100M
SystemMaxFileSize=100M
```

How many journals info on my pc.

```
sudo journalctl --disk-usage
Journals take up 8.0M on disk.
```

Now to retain only 4M with such command as below.

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=1M
journalctl: unrecognized option '--vacuum-size=1M'
```

Comment: `--vacuum-size=` and `--vacuum-time=` were added in `systemd` v. `218`

Comment: That's good to know, @don_crissti, but how do you clean up the journal in earlier versions?

Comment: @David - see [How to clear journalctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139513/22142) ;)

Comment: Been there, done that. Except the `find` thing. Is it really save to delete the .journal files manually?

Comment: are `--vacuum-size=` and `--vacuum-time=` write-only parameters? it's impossible to google how to _get_ them