# journalctl log way too big?

Tags: systemd, logs, manjaro, journalctl

I was perplexed to find that, when running for instance `journalctl -f` showed my logs to stop on Apr 20th, 8 months ago. I piped to less, `journalctl | less` and pressed `G` to go to the end, same thing.

Then I did `journalctl | less` and went down 'slowly' (`ctrl+d`), this way I was able to go way further than Apr 20th...

Theres a LOT in the logs! I think it is because there's a limit on what is being loaded. However, shouldn't the logs get rotated? Or somehow pruned without user intervention?

In my `journald.conf` `SystemMaxFileSize`/`SystemMaxUse` isn't set (a solution I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl)).
I could try the above, but I kinda want to get to the bottom of it.

I'm on **Manjaro 5.8.18-1**.

Any help or insights are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `SystemMaxFileSize=` and `RuntimeMaxFileSize=` control how large individual journal files may grow at most. This influences the granularity in which disk space is made available through rotation, i.e. deletion of historic data. Defaults to one eighth of the values configured with `SystemMaxUse=` and `RuntimeMaxUse=`, so that usually seven rotated journal files are kept as history. If the journal compact mode is enabled (enabled by default), the maximum file size is capped to 4G.

That means in theory your journald logs may occupy as much as 28GB *per* user.

To reduce the size of your logs, run `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=100M`

To avoid the issue, please define `SystemMaxUse` - I personally have:

```
cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/systemMaxUse.conf
[Journal]
SystemMaxUse=64M
```

More than enough for a home PC.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is wrong.

1. journald does, by default, limit its size, usually to 4GB. From the [documentation:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#SystemMaxUse=)

> SystemMaxUse= and RuntimeMaxUse= [...]  SystemKeepFree= and RuntimeKeepFree= [...] The first pair defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of the respective file system, but each value is capped to 4G.

2. journald does in fact rotate its logs. From the [documentation:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#SystemMaxUse=)

> SystemMaxFileSize= and RuntimeMaxFileSize= control how large individual journal files may grow at most. This influences the granularity in which disk space is made available through rotation, i.e. deletion of historic data. Defaults to one eighth of the values configured with SystemMaxUse= and RuntimeMaxUse=, so that usually seven rotated journal files are kept as history.

If all you need is a peace of mind that your logs are rotated, they already are, you don't have to do anything.

If you want to manually decrease or increase log size limit, use  `SystemMaxUse=`.

If you want to manually decrease or increase the pace at which they are rotated, use `SystemMaxFileSize=`.

Comment: The `systemd` suite has been under rapid development in recent years: note that the original question was posted in December 2020. Perhaps the then-current version of Manjaro had some bug or an error in its default configuration that prevented journald log rotation? I've also encountered systems that ostensibly had journald log rotation configured, but had in actual fact failed to rotate their journals. Fortunately, as time progresses, those bugs seem to have eventually been squashed, regardless of their origin.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just that the log is too big to navigate using `less`, it might help to get the last lines to a file, then navigate that. For example, to look at the last 20 lines:

```shellsession
$ journalctl | tail -20 > temp.txt
$ less temp.txt
```

Instead of `tail -20`, you could `grep` for a certain date or time.