# Logs are disappearing

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi

I have written a program that logs to stderr. I run it as a service with systemd. Here's the unit file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Mi Scale Translator
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/root/miscale/miscale

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Every couple of days the service stops working. When I check the status this is the output:

```
# systemctl status miscale
● miscale.service - Mi Scale Translator
   Loaded: loaded (/root/miscale.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I thought `Restart=always` would prevent exactly this, but apart from that there are also no logs:

```
# journalctl -u miscale
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-02-14 10:11:58 GMT, end at Sun 2022-12-04 20:18:38 GMT. --
-- No entries --
```

I now restarted it with `systemctl start miscale` and there are logs:

```
# journalctl -u miscale
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-02-14 10:11:58 GMT, end at Sun 2022-12-04 20:20:31 GMT. --
Dec 04 20:19:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Mi Scale Translator.
```

But I'm sure when I check again in a few days, the service will be dead again and the logs will have disappeared.

Comment: Maybe you have size limits for the journalctl. Check the file: `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and search for the value `SystemMaxUse`.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon There's a single section `[Journal]` in it and all settings including `SystemMaxUse` are commented out.

Comment: Don't you have a `Timer` (systemd unit) or a `cron` job which cleans the journal logs?  Something like `journalctl --vacuum-size=100M` is used to clear journal logs.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon It's a pretty much stock Raspberry Pi OS, I didn't configure anything. Nothing in `/etc/crontab` nor in `/var/spool/cron`.

Comment: I think `Raspberry` based Linux OS are configured by default to delete logs after certain time. Or maybe `systemd` are deleting the logs as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139515/414186) said or [this anwer](https://serverfault.com/a/931581/615456) as well.

Comment: Maybe you should set `SystemMaxUse` to a large value (and then restart with `systemctl restart systemd-journald`). You can create a service that generate a lot of logs to test when the journal is being cleared.