# How can long NoExtract in pacman.conf be written shorter still human readable?

Tags: arch-linux, wildcards, pacman

In the need for an [Arch Linux system minimal on disk space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/how-do-i-minimize-disk-space-usage), I did **NoExtract** include lots of `usr/lib/modules` ... `/drivers/` for hardware the machine will never use.

An example from **pacman.conf**:

```
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/atm*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/bluetooth*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/cdrom*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/firewire*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/infiniband*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/input/joydev*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/input/gameport*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/input/joystick*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/isdn*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/ipack*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/md*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/media*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/caif*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/can*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/dsa*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/hamradio*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/ieee802154*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/irda*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wireless*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wimax*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/nfc*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/parport*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/pcmcia*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/platform/chrome*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/thunderbolt*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/usb/atm*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/drivers/uwb*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/6lowpan*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/802*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/9p*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/atm*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/bluetooth*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/batman-adv*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/ax25*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/caif*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/can*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/dsa*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/hsr*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/ieee802154*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/irda*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/mac802154*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/nfc*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/rfkill*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/sunrpc*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/wimax*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/wireless*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/net/xfrm*
NoExtract = usr/lib/modules/[1-9]*-ARCH/kernel/sound/*
```

Because [pacman.conf seems to support shell style globbing](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/commit/?id=902305f1633298ff0ef7cd2bfbed0e91aae91646), I am wondering whether this long NoExtract string can be written significantly shorter and still being human readable too?